# How to use ctools_ajax_command_redirect with $_GET parameters

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

Is it possible to use ctools_ajax_command_redirect with $_GET Parameters ?
I am only able to redirect it to an absolute path as of now ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it

Following is the sample usage with POST param param1 with value as value1

```
ctools_ajax_command_redirect('url_path_without_base_url',0,array('query'=>array('param1'=>'value1')));
```